# Automator: how to clear 'got' items?

Tags: finder, automator

I've created an Automator workflow which (should) create a copy of a particular file in the currently selected folder. (i.e. select a folder, run the Quick Action, get a copy of the file in the folder.

However, when I run the Quick Action, I get the file and TWO copies of the folder itself, within itself. They are not links (I think), but I get a couple of iterations.

Here's the workflow:
[image]

I'm thinking that the variable "Path" is copying itself, for some reason. Possibly because it's been "Got". Is there a way to clear the "get"?

Even if I remove the "Get Selected Finder Items" action, I still get one copy of the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the options for each Action, there is a checkbox "Ignore this action's input", which means that nothing from the previous actions goes through.
Doing this on the "Get Specifed Items in Finder" action means that the folder path itself does not 'trickle down' to the Copy action.

The "Get Selected Finder Items" action is unnecessary, as the workflow already receives folders as an argument.

Comment: Exactly!  Well done.  Out of interest, what's different about what you're trying to do with the workflow vs what normally happens by pressing `⌘`+`C` then `⌘`+`V` ?

Comment: @CJK You mean the workflow of Opening a new window, navigating to the folder containing the template, arranging the two windows on the screen, and then copying and pasting...? ;-)

Comment: I meant the one where you tap `⌘`+`⟨SPACE⟩`, type in `"Dorico"`, then `⌘`+`C` and `⌘`+`V` it into your present working directory. But, I suppose a keyboard shortcut, a mouse-click, holding `⌘`, another click, and then `⌘`+`⟨BKSP⟩` probably feels like second nature by now. 

Comment: I hadn't thought about Spotlight, though I get so many results I'd have to type more to narrow it down. 
Two-finger tap, move, click is faster than 12 letters, plus movement.